# Preventing mangled names in Ada DLL

Tags: python, dll, ada, name-mangling

Is there a simple way to prevent Ada names from getting mangled when creating an Ada DLL?

Here is my .adb code

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
package body testDLL is
   procedure Print_Call is
   begin
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Hello World");
   end Print_Call;

   function Add_Nums(A,B : in Integer) return Integer is
   begin
      return A + B;
   end Add_Nums;

end testDLL;
```

my .ads

```
package testDLL is
   procedure Print_Call;
   pragma export (dll, Print_Call, "Print_Call");

   function Add_Nums(A,B : in Integer) return Integer;
   pragma export (dll, Add_Nums, "Add_Nums");
end testDLL;
```

my python

```
import ctypes

TestDLL = ctypes.WinDLL ("libTestDLL.dll")
Print_Call = getattr(TestDLL, "Print_Call@0")
Print_Call()
```

you can see that I have to add '@0' to the end of my function name, but this seems to change when I move the same code to a different compiler. This is creating some problems for me. I need either a standard mangling format or a way to remove the mangling all together.

Comment: "a different compiler" - which compilers have you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can control the object name via the Link_Name and External_Name parameters of the pragma, writing it like so:

```
pragma Export (C, Print_Call, "Print_Call", "Print_Call");
```

Alternatively, if you're using Ada2012 you can use aspects to specify these:

```
function Add_Nums(A,B : in Integer) return Integer
    with Export, Convention => Ada, Link_Name => "Add_Nums";
```

The following covers Ada's interfacing pragmas:
http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-J-15-5.html

This thread covers a little discussion revealing the differences of the two:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/comp.lang.ada/opengl/comp.lang.ada/6IVlMbtvrrU/mv3UUiDg5RwJ

Comment: I thought the thrust of the Google thread was that you (Shark8)  needed to use the **External** Name aspect. It looks as though Python is using the Link_Name; so Jon could have written `pragma Export (DLL, Print_Call, Linker_Name => "Print_Call");`. This is very confusing.

Comment: Yes, it is confusing; as I admitted there. (I frequently get the two mixed up and have to refer back to the documentation [or my now-working source-code], but I know one is the "mangled-name" and the other is the "base-name.")

I had to use external because that's the base-name, he needs to use link because that's the mangled-name.

Answer (score 3):

[Apparently](http://docs.adacore.com/gnat-unw-docs/html/gnat_rm_6.html#SEC347) (section 77) the convention `DLL` is a synonym for `StdCall`, which I understand to result in the sort of name mangling you report.

You may do better with convention `C`:

```
pragma Export (C, Print_Call, "Print_Call");
```

or even

```
pragma Export (C, Print_Call);
```

(but then the link name will be in lower case, so you'd need to change the Python `getattr()` call).

I'm assuming that there's no difference in the way the calling sequences handle the stack/parameters.